# Use Java Optional to refactor null check

Tags: java

What I am trying to achieve:

Use Java Optional to refactor null check.

Background:

I have a straightforward POJO class:

```
public record MyPojo(String someField, String someOtherField)
```

And this method:

```
    private static String question(final MyPojo mypojo) {
        if (null == mypojo) {
            return null;
        } else if (null == mypojo.someField()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return mypojo.someField().toLowerCase();
        }
    }
```

Issue:

As you can see, while super easy to understand, this code is very verbose and lengthy.
MyPojo can be bull, and so can MyPojo.someField.
I need to check those two preconditions before applying my business logic (here lower case just for example)

Question:

Is there a smarter way, either using Optional, or something smarter, to refactor this?

Comment: Is there some reason the pojo needs to allow nulls? It would be easier to forbid them when the record is created with e.g. `Objects::requireNonNull`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain your optional with .map() calls, the advantage of this approach is that it chains the operations together in a readable way and eliminates the need for explicit null checks:

```java
private static String question(final MyPojo mypojo) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(mypojo)
              .map(MyPojo::someField)
              .map(String::toLowerCase)
              .orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The old fashioned way is with the `? :` operators:

```
    private static String question(final MyPojo mypojo) {
        return (null == mypojo) ? null
            : (null == mypojo.someField()) ? null
            : mypojo.someField().toLowerCase();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First change the record:

```
public record MyPojo( String someField, String someOtherField )
{
    public MyPojo
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( someField );
        Objects.requireNonNull( someOtherField );
    }
}
```

This ensures that the attributes are never `null`.

Then `question()` can look like this:

```
private static String question( final MyPojo mypojo ) 
{
    return Objects.nonNull( myPojo ) 
        ? myPojo.someField().toLowerCase() 
        : null;
}
```

If `null` should be allowed and you insist to use `Optional`, you need to modify the Pojo like this:

```
public final class MyPojo
{
    private final String m_SomeField;
    private final String m_SomeOtherField;
    public MyPojo( String someField, String someOtherField )
    {
        m_SomeField = someField;
        m_SomeOtherField = someOtherField;
    }

    public final Optional<String> someField() {return Optional.ofNullable( m_SomeField ); }
    …
}
```

`question()` would look like this afterwards:

```
private static String question( final MyPojo mypojo ) 
{
    return Objects.nonNull( myPojo ) 
        ? myPojo.someField().map( String::toLowerCase() ).orElse( null ) 
        : null;
}
```

The approach suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76434329/1554195) works, but it is strongly discouraged to abuse `Optional` in this way as a replacement for `if-then-else` or `?-:`. See [here](https://dzone.com/articles/avoiding-pitfalls-with-java-optional-common-mistak?edition=816391&utm_campaign=&utm_content=Avoiding%20pitfalls%20with%20Java%20Optional&utm_medium=email&utm_source=dzone&utm_term=) as one reference:

> Another mistake is misusing `Optional` and treating it as a replacement  for conditional statements. Although `Optional` provides convenient methods like `orElse()` and `orElseGet()` to handle the absence of a value, using them excessively can lead to less readable code. It is important to remember that `Optional` is not intended to replace traditional `if-else` statements. Instead, it should be used when the absence of a value is a valid and expected outcome.
>
> […]
>
> […] Adhering to best practices such as preferring `Optional` as a method return type […] will enhance the readability and maintainability of your code.